# Constructing a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I have a Question (q) with many Answers, each Answer has a variety of Texts, differing in language.  I want to write a query to return all the answers in a given language (Lang) but I'm having difficulty figuring it out... here's what I'm trying:

```
List<string> Answers = q.Answers
   .Select(x => x.Texts.Where(l => l.Language.ISO == Lang).Select(t => t.Value))
   .ToList();
```

which generates:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

maybe I can't have a select inside a select... and:

```
List<string> Answers = q.Answers
   .Select(x => x.Texts.Where(l => l.Language.ISO == Lang))
   .Select(t => t.Value)
   .ToList();
```

where I would have thought the first select returns a Text, which means the second select can find its .Value... but, no:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Website.Models.Text>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Website.Models.Text>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

...perhaps I'm close but I can't quite get it.  how does one do this?

**-- Edit --**

the credit here goes to SLaks.  Here's the final statement:

```
List<string> Answers = q.Answers
        .SelectMany(x => x.Texts)
        .Where(x => x.Language.ISO == Lang)
        .Select(x => x.Value)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `.SelectMany()` to flatten the list of sets of `Text`s (`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`) into a single set of `Text`s (`IEnumerable<string>`).

Comment: laughing.  ok.  I guess there had to be a special construct for that.  thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `SelectMany` or (in LINQ syntax) a `from ... from ... select` expression:

```
var query = from answer in q.Answers
            from text in answer.Texts
            where text.Language.ISO == lang
            select text.Value;

var result = query.ToList();
```

The query selects the value of all texts in all answers to the question `q` where the text's language is `lang`.

Comment: oh, that's very cool.  I rarely use that syntax but it's nifty how you can acess and answer.Texts.  thanks.